# React material-table column resizable

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I want to know how to make material-table column resize in react.
Please help me.
I've tried the following code

```
        options={{
         sorting:false,
         resizable:true,
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please provide more lines of your code as you example, so we can see what your issue is

Comment: From my understanding material-table doesn't support resizing, are you sure you are using material-table or some other table package? All the material-table props are found here https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props

Comment: I've checked all props in material-table.com but can't finde column resizable props.
are you sure that material table is not allowed to make column resizable

Comment: Based on the link I sent, it seems that it is not possible to make columns resizable. If that is a feature that has to be there, maybe have a look at some of the alternatives, such as (Material-ui-datatables)[https://www.material-ui-datatables.com/] which has a resizable column feature

Comment: Look at this example on how to make table columns resizable as well as sortable in react: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9n3y82wov?file=/Utils.js. Material-UI does not provide option to make column widths resizable out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this feature is included under the paid DATAGRID-PRO

Comment: https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

Material UI now is not supported but you can put a div on the right edge of the header of each cell to resize its column.
Here is my solution [Resize columns table Material-ui](https://codesandbox.io/embed/resize-columns-table-material-ui-ei0pqd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2):

There is no resize path in material-ui table. you can use material-ui Data grid -(Demo Link): https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/demo/#data-grid-demo.

Or

You can rewrite the existing material-ui table style like :

```
.MuiTableHead-root .MuiTableRow-root .MuiTableCell-head {
    font-weight: bold;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow-x: overlay;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Material UI Data grid column resize is not working.

```
      [
      { field: 'id', header: 'id'},
      { field: 'count', header: 'Count', type: 'number'},
      { field: 'total', header: 'Total', type: 'number'}
       ];
```

resize should be true by default

Answer (score 2):

I have found specifying the cell style assists in manipulation of your column sizes

```
   {
        field: 'Resizing',
        title: 'Column Width',
        cellStyle: {
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
          width: '20%',
        },
   },
```